# scroling navigation bar is not working with new file in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 8 project as well and I have following Navigation bar

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div id="nav-close" class="fas fa-times"></div>
    <a href="#home">home</a>
    <a href="#idea">Idea</a>
    <a href="#about">about</a>
    <a href="#packages">packages</a>
    
</nav>
```

and I have include with main.blade.php file like this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
@include('partials._head')
    </head>

@include('partials._nav')
    <body>
//contains go here
</body>
</html>
```

and extends `main` blade file with welcome.blade.php as well like this

```
@extends('main')
```

and route in web.blade.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

now I need create another blade file like city.blade.php and make web file like

```
Route::get('/city', function () {
    return view('city');
});
```

and include nav.blade.php file with city.blade.php file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
@include('partials._nav')
</head>
<body>

// city containt goes here
</body>
</html>
```

but problem is now when I am in city blade view then I click my nav bar link it is not working here. my navigation pages are in main.blade.php so how could I fix this problem?

Comment: No Idea about solutions here

Comment: Use main blade for this city view as well, same as welcome.  You can put @yield('content') in main blade file.

Comment: @T.Shah but I do not need display main blade file contain in city blade file

Comment: could you give me some example here

Comment: @T.Shah could you explain how I use @yield('content') in city.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nav.blade.php could be

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div id="nav-close" class="fas fa-times"></div>
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}#home">home</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}#idea">Idea</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}#about">about</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}#packages">packages</a>
  
</nav>
```

main.blade.php file could be -

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
      <head>
  @include('partials._head')
      </head>

  @include('partials._nav')
      <body>
        <main>
          // content go here
          @yield('content')
        </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

welcome.blade.php could be

```
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('content')

Welcome content here

@endsection
```

city.blade.php could be -

```
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('content')

City Page content here

@endsection
```

This way you can create number of pages.

Comment: okay one more question may I need add @yield('content') to my main.blade.php file in the end of the body section

Comment: this answer navigation system solved my problem. Thanks